# 404 Error Message When Sending Gmail Draft

Tags: gmail-api

I am trying to send existing drafts in a user's gmail account.  We identify a draft to send by a thread id, so when it comes time to send, we get the full list of drafts in a user's account, and send all of the drafts that match the thread id.

```
    List<Draft> drafts = GmailAPIHelper.getDraftsAll(sender);

    for (Draft d : drafts) {
        Message m = (Message) d.get("message");
        if (m.getThreadId().equals(draftId)) {
            try {
                GmailAPIHelper.sendDraft(d, sender);
            }
            catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                if (e.getStatusCode() == 404) {
                    Logger.log("404 on draft send");
                    Logger.log(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Message sendDraft(Draft d, User u) throws IOException, NoOauthCredentialsException {
        Gmail g = GmailAPIHelper.getGmailService(u);
        Gmail.Users.Drafts.Send draftSendRequest = g.users().drafts().send("me", d);
        Message m = executeAndLog(draftSendRequest, u);
        return m;
    }
```

This works almost all the time.  However, sometimes we get a 404 response code and the following error message when we try to send the draft:

```
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not Found",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not Found"
}
```

We only send drafts that we were able to find in the user's account, and we can find the draft after getting the error - how can we be getting a "Not Found" error?

Comment: To clarify: are you able to get the draft again after the send failure?  Or does it only appear in list queries?  If you can get the draft, does it have TRASH label or any other system labels on it?

Comment: The draft appears in list queries, but cannot be obtained by id and cannot be sent.

Comment: I tried to replicate this problem, but all of my drafts could be retrieved by ID. Can you identify anything special about the broken drafts?